# UiPath - Unable to Insert ServiceNow Table Record: System.AggregateException

Tags: servicenow, uipath, uipath-studio

I am trying to automate via UiPath the insertion of data into a ServiceNow table.

I am following the step by step link
(https://connect.uipath.com/marketplace/components/servicenow-v1/media)
to automate the insertion.

However when running my project I get the following error:

[image]

I made and tested the connection with my instance normally, but this error occurs during the project run …
Can you help me?